# Monad transformer for Disjunction and Future

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I have a code returning `Future[String \/ Response]`, monad instances for both `Disjunction` and [`Future`](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib) and function `getResult: Response => [String \/ Result]`.
Now this is written with several nested functions and I want to see it as following

```
for {
  response <- getResponse
  result <- getResult(response)
} yield result   // Future[String \/ Result]
```

As I can understand Monad transformers are using exactly for this purpose and I could do [similar](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2013/12/20/scalaz-monad-transformers.html) things if I had `Option` instead of `\/`. But unfortunately I couldn't found `FutureT` nor `DisjunctionT` (although [`XorT`](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stacking-future-and-either.html#XorT+datatype) exists for cats).

So, is it possible to write monad transformer for above purpose? May be it already exist or I don't understand something.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`scalaz.EitherT`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.EitherT) to combine the effects of `\/` (Disjunction) and another monad, in your case `Future`.

```
def getResponse: Future[String \/ Response] = ???
def getResult(resp: Reponse): Future[String \/ Result] = ???

(for {
  response <- EitherT(getResponse)
  result <- EitherT(getResult(response))
} yield result).run
// Future[String \/ Result]
```

Or you could change the return types of the `getResponse` and `getResult` functions to return `EitherT` :

```
type R[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

def getResponse: R[Response] = ???
def getResult(resp: Reponse): R[Result] = ???

(for {
  response <- getResponse
  result <- getResult(response)
} yield result).run
// Future[String \/ Result]
```

Comment: Hey Peter. Thank you for pointing me to scalaz EitherT, I missed it. Unfortunately both your examples didn't work: first one because `getResult` doesn't return Future, second one because both functions didn't conformed type R[_]. Anyway, this works: `EitherT(getResponse).map(getResult).run` and slightly better than my previous implementation.
Also I'm still bit curious about what to do when you don't have transformer.

Comment: UPD: no, I'm wrong. My map results in nested Disjunction. I probably could do `join`, but that looks not elegant at all.

Comment: `map` is indeed a function from `EitherT[F, A, B]` to `EitherT[F, A, C]` so you get `EitherT[F, String, String \/ Result]`. A solution could be to use `flatMapF` :  `EitherT(getInt).flatMapF(getRes(_).point[Future]).run`.